# Why `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.ssl` properties duplicate for all kafka binders in multi-binder setup?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have an application listening to 3rd party kafka broker version 3.4.0. We have 5 subscriptions. 3 of them use same pair of trustore and keystore JKS files. Another two use separate truststore and keystore JKS files each. When we enable all subscriptions, 3 using one certificate are working fine, while other two are failing and we see such errors in logs: `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [external-topic-2]` and `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [external-topic-3]`.

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [topic-2]\n\tat org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:642)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [topic-2]
```

So messages from external-topic-2 and external-topic-3 are not coming through.
We're connecting to kafka using spring cloud libraries:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context:3.2.8'
```

Spring boot version is 2.7.5.
Here are some samples of configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: foo-bar-service
  ...
  cloud:
    discovery:
      enabled: false
    stream:
      function:
        definition: "${STREAM_FUNCTION_DEFINITION:binder1;binder2;binder3;binder4;binder5}" 
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            applicationId: ${id-unique-per-pod}
          default:
            consumer:
              startOffset: latest
              deserializationExceptionHandler: logAndContinue
      bindings:
        binder1-in-0:
          binder: kafka-1
          contentType: application/json
          destination: ${topic1}
        binder2-in-0:
          binder: kafka-2
          contentType: application/json
          destination: ${topic3}
        binder3-in-0:
          binder: kafka-3
          contentType: application/json
          destination: ${topic2}
        binder4-in-0:
          binder: kafka-4
          contentType: application/json
          destination: ${topic1}
        binder5-in-0:
          binder: kafka-5
          contentType: application/json
          destination: ${topic1}
      binders:
        kafka-1:
          type: kstream
          defaultEnvironment: false
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
              autoCreateTopics: false
              brokers: broker1.net:9093,broker2.net:9093,broker3.net:9093
              configuration:
                security.protocol: SSL
                ssl.truststore.location: trustore1.jks
                ssl.truststore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.keystore.location: keystore1.jks
                ssl.keystore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.key.password: secret-pass
        kafka-2:
          type: kstream
          defaultEnvironment: false
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
              autoCreateTopics: false
              brokers: broker1.net:9093,broker2.net:9093,broker3.net:9093
              configuration:
                security.protocol: SSL
                ssl.truststore.location: trustore3.jks
                ssl.truststore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.keystore.location: keystore3.jks
                ssl.keystore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.key.password: secret-pass
        kafka-3:
          type: kstream
          defaultEnvironment: false
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
              autoCreateTopics: false
              brokers: broker1.net:9093,broker2.net:9093,broker3.net:9093
              configuration:
                security.protocol: SSL
                ssl.truststore.location: trustore2.jks
                ssl.truststore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.keystore.location: keystore2.jks
                ssl.keystore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.key.password: secret-pass
        kafka-4:
          type: kstream
          defaultEnvironment: false
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
              autoCreateTopics: false
              brokers: broker1.net:9093,broker2.net:9093,broker3.net:9093
              configuration:
                security.protocol: SSL
                ssl.truststore.location: trustore1.jks
                ssl.truststore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.keystore.location: keystore1.jks
                ssl.keystore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.key.password: secret-pass
        kafka-5:
          type: kstream
          defaultEnvironment: false
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
              autoCreateTopics: false
              brokers: broker1.net:9093,broker2.net:9093,broker3.net:9093
              configuration:
                security.protocol: SSL
                ssl.truststore.location: trustore1.jks
                ssl.truststore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.keystore.location: keystore1.jks
                ssl.keystore.password: secret-pass
                ssl.key.password: secret-pass
```

After debugging I've spotted that ssl props of one of the binders are duplicated for all other binders. I've seen similar problem is fixed for jass: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/multi-binder-samples/kafka-multi-binder-jaas/src/main/resources/application.yml#L41C33-L41C49
Would be nice to find if there is solution for ssl.

Comment: If you always connect to the same cluster, can you clarify why you need different certs? And you should look at the printed logs for the actual internal Kafka stream config to see if your properties load correctly for each thread/binder

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, thanks for helping!
I'm a bit confused to see in logs only lines spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.ssl.keystore.location=keystore1.jks. But nothing about other files..

Comment: also multiple certs are needed cause each cert corresponds to a specific topic..

Comment: I don't have experience with Cloud Streams, but you should be able to modify logback(?) levels for Spring, in general to print out more details logs for `org.apache.kafka` package. By default, though, it should output Kafka native `StreamsConfig` section, that would be created from the Spring config